# Data-qtip is showing far away from the component on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, qtip, mousehover

When I hover over a component , it shows a data-qtip , but it shows it far away from the component.

It is happening in Extjs.
Following image added to understand about the issue. Here red dot is the component, on which when I mouse hover, tool tip coming up far away from it.
Here "Test data-qtip....." is the tooltip.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code of your component plz ?

Comment: xtype: 'component',
 html:  '<img class="help-cmp-icon"  data-qtip="text...."  data-qdismissDelay="30000" src="' +       Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL + '" />'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using "title" attribute instead of "data-qtip" in your img ?

Comment: Thanks Benoit Cuvelier.
 Its working by adding title attribute.
 But in whole application, we have been using data-qtip, only for this we have to use 'title' attribute.
Still we have to investigate why that tooltip is going away using data-qtip.